# Sub-classed TextureView not scrolling in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I've sub-classed a TextureView and want to scroll it within a ScrollView.  I've managed to get the TextureView to display, but it doesn't scroll.  Anybody have any idea why?

relevant xml code below:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:background="@drawable/back"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="0.5"
   android:orientation="vertical" >


         <ScrollView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="0.5"
             android:fillViewport="true">

             <com.proj.TableView
                 android:id="@+id/tableView1"
                 android:layout_width="1300px"
                 android:layout_height="768px" />

         </ScrollView>

         <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
              android:text="Table selected: " />

</LinearLayout>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use some layout like a container for your custom class.

```
     <ScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:fillViewport="true">

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

             <com.proj.TableView
                 android:id="@+id/tableView1"
                 android:layout_width="1300px"
                 android:layout_height="768px" />

         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
```

---

```
     <HorisontalScrollView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_contant"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horisontal" >
             <ScrollView
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="0.5"
                 android:fillViewport="true">

                 <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:orientation="vertical" >

                     <com.proj.TableView
                         android:id="@+id/tableView1"
                         android:layout_width="1300px"
                         android:layout_height="768px" />

                 </LinearLayout>
             </ScrollView>
         </LinearLayout>
     </HorisontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Well that was an incredibly basic mistake!  Cheers.

Comment: It's now scrolling vertically.  While you're here, is there a way to get it to scroll both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: I have no chance to check it, but try to use `HorisontalScrollView`. See my update

Comment: That only allows horizontal scrolling, but that's fine for my purposes. Cheers!